# slidedown table row onclick and display content

Tags: javascript

I have metadata associated with each table row , when I click on any table row  I would like to slidedown the row and display the metadata for that row then slideup to close the row .

```
I have tried using jquery slideToggle() but it display the  metadata outside the table


 $("displayRowDetails").click(function(){
 $("rowMetaData").slideToggle();
 });

<html>
  <body onload="tablemetaData()">
  <div id="divTable">
 </div>
<div id="rowMetaData">
City Description; 
Population: 
Reference: 
</div>

</body>

</html>
```

Each table row contains some metadata which should be hidden on the rowMetadata , when a row is clicked the metadata for the row is display below the row as the table row slidedown then slideup to close.

run code here: https://codepen.io/weltonash/pen/KjxZZR

table row slidedown/slideup to display row metadata

Answer (score 0):

In script you have to use `#` before id like this

```
$("#displayRowDetails").click(function(){ 
  $("#rowMetaData").slideToggle();
});
```